# Reticulate - Get Python result without assigning to variable

Tags: python, r, reticulate

If possible i would like to print the result of python Code in R (without assigning to a variable).

This works:

```
library(reticualte)
py_run_string("print(2)")
2
```

This works:

```
p = py_run_string("x = 2")
p$x
2
```

I would like this to work:

```
py_run_string("2")
2
```

Background:

I would like to read in complete python Code and capture the Output even if (print) is not used.

If i open a Python3.7 Shell and just execute "2" as a command, the Output will be "2". Here its empty.

Link to Github request: https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/595.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go with `no` after having tried this.

Tried:

```
return(
    py_run_string("2")
)
```

Tried:

```
f <- function() {
   return( 
       py_run_string("2")
   )
}

f()
```

There doesn't appear to be anything in std out

Versus:

```
b <- function() {
   return(2)
}

b()

# Out[]:  2
```

Im guessing it's accessing python's `local()` variables.

Also:

```
library(reticulate)

py_run_string("2")
ls()
# Out[1]:   None


a <- 3
ls()
# Out[2]:   'a'
```

There's nothin in R's local variables representing `py_run_string()` output

Link to Github request: https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/595.

Comment: thank you for your answer, much appreciated. I opened an issue as well on Github. If there is no update from there, i would accept your answer, ok?

Comment: yeah that's fine. fyi, i think there is a way on github issues to mark them as feature requests

Comment: i made an edit. (Accidentally to your answer as well sry).

Comment: not sure if you got a notifier on Github. Kevin Ushey provided an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I got an answer on Github from Kevin Ushey.

```
library(reticulate)

py_evaluate <- function(code) {
  builtins <- import_builtins(convert = TRUE)
  globals <- py_eval("globals()", convert = FALSE)
  locals <- globals
  parsed <- builtins$compile(code, "<string>", "single")
  builtins$eval(parsed, globals, locals)
}

py_evaluate("2")
```

See here: https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/595#issuecomment-531888843.